# How to install datastax cassandra cluster using opscenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

We are planning to install Cassandra cluster in our lab. Does anyone please tell the procedure for installing Datastax Cassandra cluster using Opscenter. Operating System : CENT OS 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is available here:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.1/opsc/online_help/opscCreatingCluster_t.html

Comment: Thankyou Ivan. I got one doubt regarding this kind of installation. Will the necessary packages downloaded through the machine where the Opscenter installed and pushed to other nodes to be installed , or the packages separately downloaded in all the nodes in cluster? Is it yum needs to be configured properly in all the machines for this?

Comment: The packages are downloaded from the internet on each node, so yum/apt-get will need to be installed, but OpsCenter will handle properly configuring repositories and such